# Xamarin deploys old code when building from PC

Tags: xamarin.forms, build-agent

I have a really weird Xamarin.Forms bug I haven't seen before: When I build and deploy to simulator or device from Visual Studio 2017 on my PC the result is not aligned with the source code. What I see is some older build.

If I build from the same branch directly with VS2017 on the Mac instead I get the expected result.

Could this be some caching issue with the Mac Build Agent? If so; is there a way to clear it to ensure it doesn't deploy older builds?

**[EDIT 1]**

I have taken all the usual dark-magic tricks such as removing/restoring all packages, cleaning the output folders and reboot the Mac before rebuilding the solution. I also made 100% sure I wasn't using old source code.

Comment: Have you done a Clear, then a project Rebuild?

Comment: I have. I have also removed and restored all packages and double- and triple checked  the source code is indeed current (removed/re-cloned) and rebooted the Mac. Pretty much can't come up with more ideas other than to ensure the build agent isn't deploying some old ipa but I don't know where it keeps its builds these days. Good question though and I updated the OP to clarify.

Comment: @JonasRembratt have you found a solution to this? i just updated to latest visual studio version and now im having this issue too. It's crippling my development so much :(

Comment: Alas, I have not. I only have one project that i splagued by this behavior and for now I can only develop using my Mac because of it. I still haven't been able to figure out where the Xamarin Mac Agent is located on the Mac so I cannot test cleaning its build folders.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I now have this same issue.

Comment: Not really. But next time it happens I would try removing the build agent's output, found as a sub folder at: `/Users/<you>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/`

Answer (score -2):

Kindly,

1. Clean the solution,
2. Uninstall the app on the emulator.
3. Close VS
4. Rename the **OBJ** folder in the project folder (same place you have the
   bin folder) to **OBJ.old** (in case you need to restore it)
5. Repeat step 4 for **BIN** folder
6. Restart the VS and open open the project
7. REBUILD the SOLUTION - you should have BIN and OBJ created for all projects.
8. Done

Comment: Well, I had already tried clearing the bin/obj folders so I doubt this would work. But I then updated the code for one of the referenced projects and suddenly the problem went away. This does not mean I solved the problem so I would still like to know where the Mac Build Agent is located and whether there's a way to clean its build output. Anyone?

Comment: That is the solution. Step 7 should be REBUILD the SOLUTION (not project). That way your problem would be gone.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I had already done all of your suggestions (except renaming obj => obj.old) and it didn't work. There seem to be some problem, possibly related to the Mac Build agent resuing old builds.

Comment: Just to be sure I finally followed you recommended solution to the letter and, as expected, it had no effect. Have you had this problem yourself and used this approach to resolve it?